# Group element in object array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, grouping

I am trying transform an array object with input data like this:

```
  var input = [
    { IdDevice: "1", Time: "11:01:00", Data: "1,12,23" },
    { IdDevice: "2", Time: "11:01:11", Data: "30,40,50" },
    { IdDevice: "1", Time: "11:02:00", Data: "5,10,21" },
    { IdDevice: "2", Time: "11:02:11", Data: "32,44,53" },
  ];
```

After some transforms:

```
  const convert = (input) =>
    Object.entries(
      input
        .flatMap(({ IdDevice, Data }) =>
          Data.split(",").map((x, i) => ({
            data: x,
            name: `device ${IdDevice} item ${i + 1}`,
          }))
        )
        .reduce(
          (a, { data, name }) => (
            (a[name] = a[name] || []), a[name].push(data), a
          ),
          {}
        )
    ).map(([name, data]) => ({ data, name }));
  var data = convert(input);
```

I have the result:

```
[
  { data: [ '1', '5' ], name: 'device 1 item 1' },
  { data: [ '12', '10' ], name: 'device 1 item 2' },
  { data: [ '23', '21' ], name: 'device 1 item 3' },
  { data: [ '30', '32' ], name: 'device 2 item 1' },
  { data: [ '40', '44' ], name: 'device 2 item 2' },
  { data: [ '50', '53' ], name: 'device 2 item 3' }
]
```

And now I want the final data will depend on *"Time"* attribute, such as: the data: "1" is in time: "11:01:00" so x:"1", y:"11:01:00" and so on...:

```
[
  { data: [
    {x:'1', y:"11:01:00"},
    {x:'5', y:"11:02:00"}
  ],
    name: 'device 1 item 1' 
  },
  { data: [
    {x:'12', y:"11:01:00"},
    {x:'10', y:"11:02:00"}
  ],
    name: 'device 1 item 2' 
  },
  ...
  { data: [
    {x:'40', y:"11:01:11"},
    {x:'44', y:"11:02:11"}
  ],
    name: 'device 2 item 2' 
  },
  { data: [
    {x:'50', y:"11:01:11"},
    {x:'53', y:"11:02:11"}
  ],
    name: 'device 2 item 3' 
  }
]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: what is the logic behind do you want to achieve? Your expected output doesn't have '30', '32' combination compared to your output

Comment: the code is so long, so I cut part of the expected output

Comment: So what is the logic? Please update your question with the logic behind. Your question ```final data will depend on "Time" attribute ``` is not clear enough.

Comment: I have updated the request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very simplified answer, maybe not what you wanted, but I believe gives the end response you want.

```js
var input = [{
    IdDevice: "1",
    Time: "11:01:00",
    Data: "1,12,23"
  },
  {
    IdDevice: "2",
    Time: "11:01:11",
    Data: "30,40,50"
  },
  {
    IdDevice: "1",
    Time: "11:02:00",
    Data: "5,10,21"
  },
  {
    IdDevice: "2",
    Time: "11:02:11",
    Data: "32,44,53"
  },
];


const convert = (input) =>
  Object.entries(
    input
    .flatMap(({
        IdDevice,
        Data,
        Time
      }) =>
      Data.split(",").map((x, i) => ({
        data: x,
        name: `device ${IdDevice} item ${i + 1}`,
        time: Time
      }))
    )
    .reduce(
      (a, {
        data,
        name,
        time
      }) => (
        (a[name] = a[name] || []), a[name].push({
          x: data,
          y: time
        }), a
      ), {}
    )
  ).map(([name, data]) => ({
    data,
    name
  }));
var data = convert(input);

console.log(data)
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "x": "1",
        "y": "11:01:00"
      },
      {
        "x": "5",
        "y": "11:02:00"
      }
    ],
    "name": "device 1 item 1"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "x": "12",
        "y": "11:01:00"
      },
      {
        "x": "10",
        "y": "11:02:00"
      }
    ],
    "name": "device 1 item 2"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "x": "23",
        "y": "11:01:00"
      },
      {
        "x": "21",
        "y": "11:02:00"
      }
    ],
    "name": "device 1 item 3"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "x": "30",
        "y": "11:01:11"
      },
      {
        "x": "32",
        "y": "11:02:11"
      }
    ],
    "name": "device 2 item 1"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "x": "40",
        "y": "11:01:11"
      },
      {
        "x": "44",
        "y": "11:02:11"
      }
    ],
    "name": "device 2 item 2"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "x": "50",
        "y": "11:01:11"
      },
      {
        "x": "53",
        "y": "11:02:11"
      }
    ],
    "name": "device 2 item 3"
  }
]
```

Comment: The output is error
```
[
  { data: [ [Object], [Object] ], name: 'device 1 item 1' },
  { data: [ [Object], [Object] ], name: 'device 1 item 2' },
  { data: [ [Object], [Object] ], name: 'device 1 item 3' },
  { data: [ [Object], [Object] ], name: 'device 2 item 1' },
  { data: [ [Object], [Object] ], name: 'device 2 item 2' },
  { data: [ [Object], [Object] ], name: 'device 2 item 3' }
]
```

Comment: Odd, it worked in my ide. Now I’m away for the next couple hours. If it’s still unsolved, I’ll revisit then

Comment: I'm looking forward to hearing from you

Comment: @CSNo.1 - the snippet isn't throwing an error. I updated my answer to show the output I get. Where are you seeing the error?

Comment: @CSNo.1, are you using Nodejs to output the result? You can try to run it in the chrome console. Or you can use JSON.stringify(output) to have a JSON format string.

Comment: Yah, SON.stringify(output) resolve the problem